# Como multiplicar una matriz por un vector

Tags: c++11

Buenas noches estoy terminando de hacer un programa para la facultad y me falta una parte de codigo para multiplicar una matriz por un vector, en este caso seria la multiplicacion del vector cantidad[i][j]*precios[j].(En el codigo esta un intento de la multiplicacion pero no funciona), si alguien me puede brindar algun tipo de ayuda se les agradeceria mucho, desde ya muchas gracias.
Aqui les dejo el codigo andando.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cantidad[3][5], precios[5], recaudacion[5], i, j, total;
    string nombresArticulos[5];

    //ingreso e imprime los nombres de los articulos
    i=0;
    while(i<5)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese los nombres de los articulos:"<<endl;
        cin>>nombresArticulos[i];
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<nombresArticulos[i]<<endl;
    }

    //guarda los precios de cada articulo
    for(j=0; j<5;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese precios de cada articulo"<<endl;
        cin>>precios[5];

    }

    //ingreso de la cantidad de articulos vendidos por cada vendedor
    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de articulos vendidos por cada vendedor: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Vendedor: "<<i+1<<" "<<"Articulo: "<<j+1<<endl;
            cin>>cantidad[i][j];
        }

    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
         for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            //cout<<"Vendedor: "<<i+1<<" "<<"Articulo: "<<j+1<<endl;
            cout<<cantidad[i][j]<<endl;
        }

    }

    //cantidad de dinero recaudado por cada vendedor
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            recaudacion[j]=cantidad[i][j]*precios[j];
        }

    }

    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout<<recaudacion[j]<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias contarnos que intentaste para hacer la multiplicacion y donde tuviste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que estás calculando el dinero recaudado por cada vendedor. Y dado que en tu programa defines tres vendedores, el vector `resultado` deberá tener 3 elementos... no 5.

```
int recaudacion[3];
```

Pues bien, llegados a este punto, tu ejercicio se resuelve aplicando la teoría de multiplicación de matrices. Esto es, dado una matriz de 3x5 y otra de 5x1, obtendremos una de 3x1. Teoría de multiplicación de matrices [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicaci%C3%B3n_de_matrices).

Al multiplicar matrices, en cada celda de la matriz resultado no se almacena un único producto, sino una suma de productos... es importante no olvidarse inicializar las variables:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  recaudacion[i] = 0;
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
  {
    recaudacion[i] += cantidad[i][j]*precios[j];
  }
}
```

Y, por favor, no declares **todas** las variables al inicio de la función. Procura reducir su vida al máximo. Conseguirás programas más legibles y con menos errores.